# JQ question about parsing dictionaries within lists

Tags: json, jq, data-wrangling

I have a json file in the following format

```json
{
  "a": [
    [
      {
        "p": "p1-value",
        "d": "d1-value"
      },
      {
        "p": "p2-value",
        "d": "d2-value"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "p": "p3-value",
        "d": "d3-value"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "z": [
    [
      {
        "p": "p1-value",
        "d": "d1-value"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and I'd like to know how to output something like this

```
a p1-value
a p2-value
a p3-value
z p1-value
```

I've tried a few different jq queries but I can't get it to work.

I know I can use 'keys[]' at the top level but that doesn't give me anything below it. I've tried `."a" | .[] | .[] | .path` but that means I have to specify each top level key..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use [`to_entries`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries-from_entries-with_entries) to create an array of key-value pairs, which you can access by using `.key` and `.value`:

```bash
to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value[][].p)"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/h0b6GUbzhV3)

Or fetch just the keys using [`keys_unsorted`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#keys-keys_unsorted), bind them to a variable using `as`, and access the fields using the variable:

```bash
keys_unsorted[] as $key | "\($key) \(.[$key][][].p)"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/paZJDui3J3v)

In both cases I used [string interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation) `"\(…)"` to construct the final values, but depending on your processing pipeline, there might be better ways.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for the super quick response. Both options work perfectly.